# Alignment in flextable correct in Rstudio viewer, incorrect in Word

Tags: alignment, flextable, officer

I am trying to left align some columns in a few of my tables. Most of the time this works no problem, but other times, the columns selected with:

```
ft <-align(ft, j=1:2, align = "left", part = "body")

ft <-align(ft, j=4:6, align = "left", part = "body")
```

look correct in the Rstudio viewer. I used a loop to make 39 tables and want to add them to a word document using officer

However, when printed to a word doc using:

```
doc <- read_docx() %>%
body_add_flextable(tab0)

body_add_break(doc, pos="after")

for (i in 1:38) {
  body_add_flextable(doc,get(paste0("tab", i)), align = "left")
  body_add_break(doc, pos="after")
}

print(doc,target=documentname)
```

it center aligns the columns (only changes those that were left aligned). When I click on the text, it says that they are left aligned, but then I center and re-left align and that fixes the issue. I have only noticed the issue which character variables

I tried triming whitespace with
`trimws()` before I make the flextable with no luck.

I tried other alignments and the issue only seems to occur with left alignment.

I don't believe my code to be wrong, since it works for my other tables. Therefore, I think trying to make reproducible code would be a waste of time.

Therefore, I'm assuming the text itself is causing the issue? Does anyone know what could be wrong with the character variables themselves? Or any other ideas?

Comment: could you provide a full reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it...

Somewhere within my flextable manipulation this leading white space was added.

So trimming white space before didn't do anything. Had to trim right before naming my table (within a loop). Here is the loop I used to correct it.

```
for (j in 1: length(ft[["body"]][["content"]][["content"]][["data"]])){
       ft[["body"]][["content"]][["content"]][["data"]][[j]][["txt"]] <- trimws(ft[["body"]][["content"]][["content"]][["data"]][[j]][["txt"]])
}
```

Comment: hi, please use only exposed API, using the underlying data structure make your code fragile as these structures could change over time.